# insert data in tree in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to output table from `tbl_ledger_input`

My code is :

```
select  parent_code ledger_code,
        max(name) name,
        4 depth,
        max(CONCAT(SUBSTR(LEDGER_CODE,1,5),'0000')) PARENT_CODE,
        select sum(balance) balance
        from   tbl_ledger_input
        group by eff_date,
                 ledger_code,
                 balance,
                 ref_cur_id,
                 eff_date,
                 ref_branch,
                 cur_balance
        order by eff_date,
                 ref_cur_id,
                 eff_date,
                 ref_branch,
                 sum(cur_balance) cur_balance,
                 number_date
from   tbl_ledger_branch
where  depth =5
group by parent_code,ref_cur_id,eff_date,ref_branch,number_date ;
```

I got this error :

```
ORA-00936: missing expression
```

Comment: Syntax is not correct, there is two selects and multiple group by in same query. Add some brackets if you are trying to use sub query.

Answer (score 1):

Code you posted is somewhat *messy*;

- `select` (in the 1st line) should be enclosed into parenthesis
- I presume that next 3 lines also belong to it.
- You *can* use a subquery, but it **must** return at most 1 row - otherwise you'll get too_many_rows error
- Also, you can't use `order by` in there

This is code that might be OK (as far as syntax is concerned):

```
  SELECT parent_code ledger_code,
         MAX (name) name,
         4  DEPTH,
         MAX (CONCAT (SUBSTR (LEDGER_CODE, 1, 5), '0000')) PARENT_CODE,
         (  SELECT SUM (balance) balance
              FROM tbl_ledger_input
          GROUP BY eff_date,
                   ledger_code,
                   balance,
                   ref_cur_id,
                   eff_date,
                   ref_branch,
                   cur_balance)
    -- order by eff_date ,  ref_cur_id  ,  eff_date  ,  ref_branch  ,  sum(cur_balance) cur_balance  , number_date
    FROM tbl_ledger_branch
   WHERE DEPTH = 5
GROUP BY parent_code,
         ref_cur_id,
         eff_date,
         ref_branch,
         number_date;
```

but - in my opinion - it is wrong. I doubt that subquery will actually return only one row, so - you'll get an error.

Therefore, use another option. Maybe

- you should **join** `tbl_ledger_input` and `tbl_ledger_branch`
- or, use queries separately (as subqueries or CTEs) and then merge the result
- or, **correlate** subquery so that it really returns only one row
- or something else

Comment: I run this code and I got this error : ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: I'm glad you ran that code. I'm sorry you **didn't read everything I wrote**, but I do suggest you do it now.